# PHP mbstring.func_overload ignored in .user.ini

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have mbstring.func_overload = 7 in my php.ini, and I need to have it set to 0 for one directory. I have found out I cannot use .htaccess when using PHP via mod_fcgid as I do in my Debian installation.

I have created a .user.ini in the directory where I want this setting set to 0 and I also placed a test.php containing a phpinfo(); line inside the same directory, to see if this .user.ini takes effect.

Beside of the setting above that I WANT to change I also put some other PHP settings in this .user.ini files which I will not keep there, they are just to notice if something actually changes.

My .user.ini:

```
post_max_size = 12M
upload_max_filesize = 128M

[Date]
date.timezone = "UTC"

[mbstring]
mbstring.language = German
mbstring.func_overload = 0
```

The strange thing is: all the above settings are accepted and shown as they are in my .user.ini when  requesting the test.php file, as "local" settings, except one: mbstring.func_overload is still 7 both for local and global configuration.

[image]

Any hints why mbstring.func_overload is ignored while other PHP settings in my .user.ini work perfectly?

Comment: When and if you apply this change in the `php.ini` make sure to do so inside the other `php.ini` file and restart your apache server. That could be one of the problems

Comment: I am sorry, but I didn't understand your comment. What did you mean by if I apply this change in php.ini, then also apply it in the other php.ini? Btw.: I had restarted my apache every time I added or modified some of the configuration variables.

Comment: I meant that there are two php.ini files, and you should modify them first and restart your server

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem. I can change any mbstrings-settings in .user.ini, but not mbstring.func_overload.

UPD: I found a reason - mbstring.func_overload can't be redefined in .user.ini, because have status PHP_INI_SYSTEM.

[This setting can only be changed from the php.ini file.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.configuration.php#ini.mbstring.func-overload)

Solution. Add follow lines into nginx.conf:

`

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "date.timezone='Europe/Berlin'
        mbstring.func_overload=2
        memory_limit=1024M";
        ...another fastcgi-options...
    }
```

`